# rspec with "should_receive" expectation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

Below is error and the spec listed for my failing test , not sure why it keep getting failed with following message even though I see the method getting invoked on `@user.save`

```
Failure/Error: expect(@performer).should_receive(:store_performer)
       (#<RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationTarget:0x007f9ec42b5808>).store_performer(any args)
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

Once again
**if I comment the** `should_receive` **I do see the method getting invoked (confirmed by virtue of puts) on** `@user.save` call (During that I also examine the object_id of @performer inside the spec and inside the invoked method and found them to be same)

Note: Basically the `store_performer` , `update_minimum_payout` and `update_to_be_paid` are after_save callback

FYI the test case

```
it 'should invoke callback method' do
  new_single_performer
  @performer = @user.performer
  expect(@performer).should_receive(:store_performer)
  expect(@performer).should_receive(:update_minimum_payout)
  expect(@performer).should_receive(:update_to_be_paid)
  @user.save
end
```

### User.rb

```
class User <  ActiveRecord::Base

  # Activity Log (formerly called User Activity)
  cattr_accessor :current_user



  has_one :performer,
    :dependent => :destroy, :validate => true,:inverse_of => :user,:include => :profile # auto load the profile
  ## Some more association
 
  scope :performers, where(:is_performer => true)
  scope :active, where(:active => true)
  ## Some more scope

  ## Validation
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :email #, :password, :password_confirmation
  validates_presence_of :site_id, :unless => :is_referrer?
  validates_format_of :first_name, :message => "Characters not allowed: $\#@!^&*(){}", :with => /^[\w\s]+z/
  validates_format_of :last_name, :message => "Characters not allowed: $\#@!^&*(){}", :with => /^[\w\s]+z/
  validates_format_of :email,  :message => "Invalid Email address", :with => /[\w\.\-\@]+z/
  before_save :geocode, :if => :should_change_geocode?
  before_save :check_role
  after_create :update_vendor_id
  after_create :notify_admin
  after_save  :store_changes,:if => :if_changed?
  after_save :setup_account,:if => :studio_active_changed?
  after_save :approval_notification,:if => :send_notification_present?
```

end

### Performer.rb

```
class Performer < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :user, :conditions => {:is_performer => true},:inverse_of => :performer
  # validations
  validates :date_of_birth, :address_1, :city, :state, :zipcode, :country, :phone_number, 

  after_save :store_performer
  after_destroy :destroy_performer_source
  after_save :update_minimum_payout ,:if => :minimum_payout_changed?
  after_save :update_to_be_paid ,:if => :include_in_payouts_changed?

  private
    def store_performer
      ## Performer Source is Mongo document
      performer_source = PerformerSource.find_or_create_by(:performer_id => self.id)
      performer_source.update_attributes(performer_hash)
      performer_source
    end
   
    def update_minimum_payout
      self.current_payout.update_attributes(:minimum_payout => self.minimum_payout)
    end

    def update_to_be_paid    
      self.current_payout.update_attributes(:to_be_paid => self.include_in_payouts)
    end
end
```

### PerformerSource

```
 class PerformerSource
    include Mongoid::Document
   end
```

JFI my  `Rspec Version` is 2.12.2

Comment: Does the test pass if you only have one expect statement? i.e. comment out  `expect(@performer).should_receive(:update_minimum_payout)` and `expect(@performer).should_receive(:update_to_be_paid)`

Comment: @Yule Nope didn't help sorry

Comment: What about if you call the expect on @user.performer, rather than @performer. So `expect(@user.performer).should_receive(:store_performer)`

Comment: One other thing `During that I also examine the object_id of @performer inside the spec and inside the invoked method and found them to be same`

Comment: Please show: your app/models/performer.rb model code, your db/schema.rb section for Performer and the controller code for the callbacks

Comment: Check if `@user` is valid in spec and `save` returns true. My idea is: maybe you are trying to save invalid object and callbacks are not called because saving is stopped before.

Comment: @gotva I did this expect(@user.persisted?).to be_true the record did got saved FYI I commented all the other expect that are mention above

Comment: Syntax looks wrong--shouldn't that be either `expect(@peformer).to receive` or `@performer.should_receive`?

Comment: @zetetic Nope the syntax is correct the one you mention is part of latest rspec and not part of rpsec 2.12.2.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment @Ratatouille - try swapping out `expect(@performer).should_receive(:store_performer)` and replacing it with `@performer.should_receive(:store_performer)`

Comment: @zetetic yup that worked I tried that just few hours before you replied and it worked thanks anyway